# Put html code in textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div whose innerHTML i want to put it in textarea, the problem is that the div content is with html tags and when i place that in textarea it does not show the executed html code but it shows text with html tags.
      I want the executed html code in the textarea, how can I achieve this?
      I have searched all through the net but not able to find it.
      Any kind of help will be highly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you want to see in the text area?

Comment: Could you replace the textarea with a div? Why are you using a textarea element?

Comment: @Jivings I think he wants to see the text rendered in the textarea as it would have been rendered in the div.

Comment: You need to use some WYSIWYG Editor, TinyMCE for example http://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: textarea is for text only. you cannot put any html tags in it. if you do need any maekup, just use a simple div.

Comment: its an email functionality, in which when we click on reply the static contents opens in new window being editable

Comment: you can the contenteditable = true answer and Send their data using innerHTML :$(div).[rowNumber].innerHTML;

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `textarea` you can use `div` with [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Content_Editable) attribute:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  This text can be edited by the user.
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried that but i also have to send that contents of the div with contenteditable true, so instead of sending the text it sends tags

Comment: Send their innerHTML content :$(div).[rowNumber].innerHTML;

Comment: I am sending the innerHTML contents but that has html tags in it

Comment: @EricIlavia I am still confused,about what are trying to achieve. At first, you were trying to view executed code in textarea, then you were trying to send only the text.Little bit strange ?!